# Different DataSource to DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a DataTable.

CurrencyId | Currency

---

0     | USD

1     | Baht

2     | Euro

5     | Rupee

6     | Yen

I have bound this table to a DataGridViewCombobox Cell. The user can choose one currency once. If the user choose 'USD' at first DataGridViewRow, the combobox of the next row would be without 'USD'. Can I get it? I have tried this.

```
 private void setCellComboBoxItems(DataGridView dataGrid, int rowIndex, int colIndex,   DataTable itemsToAdd)
  {
      DataGridViewComboBoxCell currencycell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];

      currencycell.DataSource = dtCurrency;
      currencycell.ValueMember = "CurrencyId";
      currencycell.DisplayMember = "CurrencyShortName";
  }
```

i can't modify the DataSource Property. How can i get it? Thanks.

Comment: Maintain tmp data table and remove the selected value from the data table and bind the tmp data table to `currencycell.DataSource `

Comment: When I bind the tmp data table to currencycell.DataSource, the selected value of the above cell is disappeared. @Damith

Answer (score 0):

Have a copy of the datasource where you remove the the selected value which you use as datasource for display.

Subscribe to `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event, then get the combobox from the editing control like below and set its datasource to the copy of the datasource.

Sample Code:

```
void myDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.DataSource = displayDataSource;
        }
    }
```